# Корректно ли возвращать ResponseEntity(null, HttpStatus.OK)?

Tags: java, spring, null, controller

Коллеги, у меня в контроллере возвращается `ResponseEntity<Object>`  с целью вернуть объект ошибки. Если ошибки нет, то нужно вернуть просто Ок 200. Корректно ли возвращать null при этом, или как лучше поступить?

```java
@PutMapping
public ResponseEntity<Object> update(@RequestBody @Valid EmployeeDTO employeeDTO) {
    
    var id = employeeDTO.getId();
    var employee = employeeService.findById(id).orElse(null);
    
    if (employee == null) {
        var error = new ErrorResponse("Не найден сотрудник");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(error, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    
    employeeService.save(employee);
    
    //--- КОРРЕКТНО ЛИ ТАК? ---
    return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, такой вариант [приемлем](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63390389/responseentity-ok-without-response-body)

Также можно воспользоваться билдером [`ResponseEntity.ok`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html#ok--):

```java
//...
return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
```